# Setting a Javascript variable in google chart

Tags: javascript, variables, charts

I read a variable from the url and I want to use this in my chart. Below is the code I use.. it works fine (it's printed on the screen) but when I want to use it in my chart it simply shows $1 in the label.. (see the bottom line of the code).
Any ideas?

```
<!-- set default value for SSI variable "data" -->
<!--#set var="data" value="" -->

<!-- get "data" value from URL -->
<!--#if expr="$QUERY_STRING = /data=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/" -->
<!--#set var="data" value="$1" -->
<!--#endif -->

<!-- print the "data" value -->
<!--#echo var="data" -->
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
   google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

function drawVisualization() {
  // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Week',  '$1']
```

Comment: The bottom part;   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Week',  '$1']

Comment: Javascript is not Java

Comment: Yes sorry.. I changed the title already..

Answer (score 0):

Just putting this in the last line fixed the problem..

> ```
> ['Week',  '<!--#echo var="data" -->']
> ```